# Include CSS to module specific template

Tags: 7, theming

I have a custom module which contains a template directory and a `.tpl.php`. I would like to add a specific stylesheet for this template. Right now, my tpl-file looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-1.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>My Title</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sites/all/themes/mytheme/css/styles.css" />
</head>
  <body>
    <div class="content-container">
        <p>My content</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And it works, but only partially... How can I include the css stylesheet in a more proper (read: more Drupal) way? I've tried the `drupal_add_css()`, but with no results... But maybe I did it the wrong way. Any suggestions?

Comment: Consider putting `<html>` in new line, now it looks like you forgot it on first glance.

Answer (score 1):

In `mymodule.info` file, add following line:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/styles.css
```

Then, in `html.tpl.php` be sure to print scripts and styles, like that:

```
  <?php print $styles; ?>
  <?php print $scripts; ?>
</head>
```

Failing to output these will break many modules, and make Drupal Core to fallback to non-javascript behavior, and you don't want this to happen.

Comment: That won't work (neither will `drupal_add_css()`) as OP is replacing the the html template. The template needs to be preprocessed, a `$styles` var instantiated via `drupal_get_css()`, then `print $styles` added to the `<head>` of the page to use any of the in-built CSS-adding methods

Comment: @Clive I somehow missed that he does not `print $styles;`. Updating my answer. Again, some things are so obvious now, it's easy to forget they are not obvious for everyone. Sorry.

Comment: Do I have to print the `$styles` in my custom .tpl file? Or the general html.tpl? Because if insert it into my custom .tpl, I get a `Undefined variable: styles`-error...

Comment: @Michiel You are supposed to print `<head>` only in `html.tpl.php`, no matter if it's module or theme provided. And every time you do it, be sure to print them `$styles` and `$scripts`, unless you know enough to be sure you don't want to.